# Are locked environments faster than unlocked environments?

Tags: r

I noticed the `lockEnvironment` function and was wondering if/when I should use it for environments.  I often use environments as lookup tables because, being hash tables, they're faster than lists.  Can locking an environment improve performance?

I did some testing but couldn't find a difference:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> lst = as.list(paste0(rep(letters,each=10),1:10))
> names(lst) = lst
> a = list2env(lst,hash=TRUE,parent=emptyenv())
> b = list2env(lst,hash=TRUE,parent=emptyenv())
> lockEnvironment(b,bindings=TRUE)
> microbenchmark(a$z1,b$z1)
Unit: nanoseconds
 expr min  lq median    uq  max neval
 a$z1 612 615  623.5 679.0 6238   100
 b$z1 613 615  619.5 675.5 1943   100
```

Is locking just a reliability feature or are there ever performance differences?

Comment: You haven't used `lockEnvironment` in your example. Furthermore your example is so trivial that it doesn't work on my machine - microbenchmark measures a negative execution time!

Comment: Ha!  I was trying to keep it simple, but accidentally took away the whole point.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lockEnvironment` is used primarily internally by R to lock the package environment after loading.  There shouldn't be any performance impact for locking the environment either good or bad.

Comment: Thanks!  I expected that was the case but wasn't sure if the locked binding somehow sped up symbol lookup.